# How can i create property sheet inheritance with Ant?

Tags: inheritance, ant, multiple-inheritance

I'd like to create a build system in Ant which makes heavy use of property inheritance.

I see that Ant allows in a .properties file as input, however, i'd like to input multiple properties files perhaps with some values overriding others.

Is this even possible using Ant or do i need to write it myself and to create the final .properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use multiple properties files - the important thing to keep in mind though, is that Ant properties are immutable - once set, they cannot be changed. So the first properties file to set a property wins. Given this, you should begin with the 'most specific' file first and include the default or the parent file last.

Here's [an article that talks about this](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/articles/article.asp?p=519946&seqNum=2) in some detail. From the command line, you might do this:

```
ant -propertyfile level_2.properties -propertyfile level_1.properties -propertyfile base.properties
```

Properties defined in `level_2` will 'override' properties with the same names in `level_1` which in turn override properties in `base`.